# Regex issue about non-capturing String in PHP

Tags: php, regex

there is an error in my regrex code, or there  is a bug in regex

i want to match string, but not include specific string

here is the code [MY CODE](https://regex101.com/r/sZ6eA7/2)

the problem is the 'j' character not match anything

Comment: can you edit your question to make it clear what you are looking for exactly: what you expect your code to do?

Comment: Your code should be here. Is there PHP in question here? What are the rules you are trying to match?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need this RegExp `([^.])`

Coment related update:
this RegExp will match all symbols except those wich are in [] with prefix ^ (it means NOT)

Comment: Answers should have an explanation.

Comment: added some explanation

Answer (score -1):

*your question is vague and should include a little more context of what your trying to achieve.
but to answer your question directly:*

no regex is not broken. "jln" does not have a period after it so it will not match. either peroid your jln in the input, or remove the requirement of the period character in the jln position.

regex correction;

```
((?:(?!jl|[.?!]).|Jl\.|jl\.|jln).+?[.?!\n\r]+\s+)
```